# Ending a Visual Studio loadtest user session if a website error is hit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I'm using a VS2010 loadtest against a website, but the site being tested is throwing some errors (eg, SiteUnavailable or other general site-specific errors).

The loadtest continues execution even if an error is returned in the response - so our .NET server logs are showing many errors for a single user session - and the subsequent errors may well be caused because we are trying to continue a web journey that should really have ended.

So is it possible to end the erroring user session as soon as an error is hit in a loadtest *without* ending the whole loadtest?  I would then want the virtual user to continue with another new web journey.

My loadtest is not scripted (it's using the default view) as I read somewhere that loadtests are less efficient when scripted.

However I can't see a setting that would enable me to do what I want, so I'm thinking that scripting would be the way to go.

Any pointers/suggestions gratefully received.
Dave

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else needs the answer to this, I had it answered via the MS forum.  There is a setting in the webtest "StopOnError" - this should be set to True and will end the webtest running, NOT the loadtest, if an error occurs.  This setting avoids the chain of potentially unrelated errors that may occur as a result of a single error.